# Independence of random variables and combinations with Dirichlet example

Tags: probability, random-variables, independence

In General is the statement : if X , Y and Z are independent random variables, is X+Y and Y+Z independent of each other?

In my case, I have $Z_i = gamma(1)$ and we take $(X , Y) = \frac{(Z_1 + Z_2 , Z_2 + Z_3)}{Z_1 + Z_2 + Z_3 + Z_4} = Dirichlet_{.2.}(2,2,4)$ . I am trying to find if X is independent of Y.

I managed to show that cov(X , Y) = 0, but 0 correlation does not imply independence.
and I managed to show that $(U_1 , U_2 , U_3) = \frac{(Z_1 , Z_2 , Z_3)}{Z_1 + Z_2 + Z_3 + Z_4}$ has $cov(U_i,U_j) \neq 0 \text{ for } i \neq j$ . Note : $(X,Y) = (U_1 + U_2 , U_2 + U_3)$

Maybe we can show using f(X,Y) = f(X)f(Y). But I get stuck in the derivation.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you can think of X and Z being very small, and Y being very large, there is no way X+Y and Y+Z being independent

Comment: More formally, let $X=Z=0$ and $Y$ be an arbitrary non-degenerate random variable.

Comment: I see how that makes sense!